# Extending/Accessing Managed Package

Tags: managed-package

I'm new to Salesforce development and I've been tasked to add some functionality.

We have installed an app (specifically "Zendesk for Salesforce") which syncs data from Salesforce to Zendesk via a REST API.

The app contains API authentication details.

What I would like to do is extend the app (managed package) to send some more data to Zendesk.

Ideally I would like to be able to call functions/classes from the app instead of using the base HTTP classes. 
If that isn't possible I would like to access the authentication details stored in the app so that they are only in one place.

Is this possible, or am I going to have to duplicate some of the access and functionality of the managed package?

Hope that makes sense, I'm on a bit of a crash course.

Comment: "...so the are only in once place" might make more sense as "...so they are only in one place", but I'm not positive that is what's intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

welcome to SFSE!

You can't see or access any code that's inside a managed package, but you can see and call methods that have been marked as `global` by the package provider. If they've not provided an interface in this manner then I think you're only real option will be to duplicate some of the functionality yourself like you say. Before going that route though I'd get in touch with the package provider and see what's possible and what isn't.